# Induction with summation. How to factor out

Tags: induction

[image]

Hey Everyone,

So here is the problem I am currently working on and I have a few questions with what I can factor our of the sigma notation in order to use the IH.

Base Case: $1$ is the base case $1 = 1$

IH: Basically Restate the Question

WTP:  $n+1$ holds for this equation. How I understand that the right side of the equation ends up looking like $(n+2)(n+1)! - 1$. However I am confused about the left side of the equation.

Plugging n+1 into the sigma notation I get the highest term where $k = n+1$ to be $((n+1)\cdot (n+1)!)$. Now how do I go about factoring this out? I want it to look like the original LHS of the equation when $k = n$ so I can use my IH. So you can factor into $((n+1)\cdot (n+1)(n)!)$.

But where do I go from here? I am completely stuck and dont know how to factor further.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*} \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k(k!) &= \sum_{k=1}^n k(k!) + (n+1)(n+1)!\\& = (n+1)!-1+(n+1)(n+1)! \\&= (n+1)!(1+n+1)-1 \\&= (n+2)!-1.\end{align*}

Comment: I would phrase this as "If (what is true for n) then the result for n+1 is ...)".